# Execute string (Containing variables in a string) in a IF condition

Tags: php, if-statement, dynamic-controls, dynamic-columns

I am writing a PHP library in which i want to create a dynamic string which execute in a `IF` statement. Below is the scenario.

**Controller Code**

```
$config = [
    'option' => [
        'exclude' => [
            'system_account' => 1,
            'postable_account' => 0
        ]
    ]
];

$drop_down_generator = new DropDownOptionsGenerator($config);
$drop_down_generator->generateMarkup($result);
```

**Library Code**

```
$exclude = $this->config['option']['exclude'];
$exclude_condition = '';
if (!empty($exclude)) {
    //Generating IF Statemnet Condition String. Multiple Condtions can be sent from the Controller
    foreach ($exclude as $key => $condition_value) {
        $exclude_condition .= (empty($exclude_condition)) ? '$row->' . $key . ' == "' . $condition_value . '"' : ' && $row->' . $key . ' == "' . $condition_value . '"';
    }
}

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    // Here is the Problem, As you can see below the output of the $exclude_condition variable containing $row variable
    // which is not executing in the "IF" statement
    // Output of $exclude_statement => $row->system_account == "1" && $row->postable_account == "0"
    if (! $exclude_condition) {
        $output .= sprintf($this->option_format, $row->$value, '', $row->$label);
    }
}
```

In short Words: How can i execute string which contains multiple variables in `IF` Condition ?

OR

Suggest me another best solution to solve my Problem.

Comment: You could use `eval()`.

Comment: eval()  is very dangerous and discouraged to use by php.net documentation, that's why i am posting my question.

Comment: it's dangerous if you use it with user-supplied data. It's fine for processing your own configuration file.

Comment: just the one reason for not to use or there any other reason ?

Comment: If you use it with user input, they can supply input that will run any PHP function, so they could overwrite files, send mail, etc. But if you use it with input that you know is safe, then it's not a problem.